# bad indentation of a mapping entry with posts

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I'm new to swagger , I understand the concepts but I got an error when I try to test the concept "bad indentation of a mapping entry" , I Hope if anyone can help me to find the mistake , I need to know also when I work on a big project should i do this manually for each method or when I integrate the swagger with express.js it will generated automatically ?

```html
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: |
    This is a sample Petstore server.  You can find 
    out more about Swagger at 
    [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on 
    [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger ITShare Test
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/
  contact:
    email: apiteam@swagger.io
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
# host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
# basePath: /
tags:
- name: posts
  description: Operations about user
  externalDocs:
    description: Find out more about our store
    url: http://swagger.io
# schemes:
# - http
paths:
  /posts
    get:
      tags:
      - posts
      summary: Get POSTS
      operationId: getPosts
      produces:
      - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: successful operation
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Post'
        400:
          description: Invalid POST supplied
        404:
          description: User not found
definitions:
  Post:
    type: object
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      userId :
        type: integer
        format: int64
      title:
        type: string
      body:
        type: string
    xml:
      name: User
externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about Swagger
  url: http://swagger.io
# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
basePath: /
schemes:
 - http
```

Comment: not a swagger user, but [validating this yaml](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator), shows that there should be a colon after "/posts" -> "/posts:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 27 there should be:

`/posts:`

instead of:

`/posts`

When integrating swagger with express.js I can't help you though..